# Adding a method to pass the unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, junit

I have this unit test:

```
      private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      @Test
      public void testLog_C_Indent_String() {
        String message = "hallo";
        IMyLog instance = getInstance();

        instance.setLogFile(null);
        instance.setLogConsole(true);
        instance.setIndent(3);
        instance.log(message);

        String expectedPrefix = "\t\t\t";
        String expectedText = expectedPrefix + message;
        String result = outContent.toString();

        assertTrue("The output is expected to be offset by 3 tabs.",
            result.startsWith(expectedPrefix)
                ||
                result.contains(expectedText));
      }
```

I need to add a method that will give the message "hallo" with \t\t\t the result will be "\t\t\thallo".I did this method, but every time I get a message:"The output is expected to be offset by 3 tabs."

```
      private boolean logConsole = true;
      private String logFile;
      private int indent = 0;

      public void log(String message) {
            try {
                if (this.logConsole) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
                if (logFile.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("file is empty");
                } else {
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(logFile, "UTF-8");

                    for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                        writer.println("\t");
                    }
                    writer.println();
                    writer.println(message);
                    writer.close();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException | NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that `println()` appends a newline? So really your string looks like this:

```java
"\t\n\t\n\t\n\nhallo\n"
```

Try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                        writer.print("\t");
                    }

                    writer.print(message);
                    writer.close();
```

Comment: it did not help :(

Comment: @TomášBajgar when in doubt, add print() statements to help you debug